# C++ constructor map object (Edited)

Tags: c++, object, dictionary, copy-constructor

I searched a lot but I couldn't find the answer of my question:

I have a class **Student** with lots of field so I don't want to use **copy constructor**.

I should save the data from a file into a map.

I read a line from file (all the student information saved in a line) and with a function (**readLine**) which is a public member of **Student** class, I decode the line and save it to current student:

```
getline(in, line);//read a line
Student s;
s.readLine(line);//Decode the line and save it into s
```

I wrote before:

```
map<string, Student> students; //map of student key=student ID.
```

When I use these lines an error will happen

`students[Student::getID(line)]=Student(s);`

or

```
students[Student::getID(line)]=s;
```

**Exception Code:   c0000374**

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks.

### **Edited**

I tried to use the copy constructor but it didn't run:

```
Student(const Student &s){
     cout<<"COPY";
}
```

Calling:

```
Student s;
s.readLine(line);
students[Student::getID(line)]=Student(s);
```

Destructor:

```
~Student(){
..
.
delete [] exam;
.
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with a copy constructor?

Comment: I should write lots of code for copy each field.
If there is just this method I have to use it.

Comment: Do you have peculiar fields so the compiler can't generate the constructor for you? It sounds unlikely for a student class. (It also seems unlikely that there are more than a few.)

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for your map? You could use something like students.insert(std::make_pair(Student::getID(line),s));

Comment: [molbdnilo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo): There are some fields for saving the marks which are dynamic.

Comment: [qutab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1807558/qutab) I uses **a[key]=value;** for insert into map.
`students[Student::getID(line)]=Student(s);`

Comment: How does the constructor and destructor of Student looks like? Also can you share what Student::getID(line) returns?

Comment: I put destructor and constructor on the question

Comment: Okay here's I think what happens in this case. The map destructor will call destructor of every key and value in the map. So when your Student object on the stack goes out of scope, it's destructor is called and once again when your map is destructed resulting in undefined behavior. Because you will be `delete [] exam;` ing twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for I all who wanted to solve my problem.

I found the problem.

For defining the map of objects it's better that registering the address of object instead of object.

```
map<string, Student> students
```

changed to

```
map<string, Student*> students
```

And Also as my friend **molbdnilo** said I used copy constructor.

Comment: This is not a very good solution as it introduces manual memory management. It's better to use `map<string, Student>` but make other changes to avoid unwanted copies.

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem.
If I use `map<string, Student> students` the value of map will changed without my edition by itself.
I become crazy.